incompressible boundary and cusps for hyperbolic n-manifolds
I'm reading the Feng Luo, Stephan Tillmann and Saul Schleimer paper "Geodesic Ideal Triangulations Exist Virtually". In there there is the follwing phrase:
"A subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ is termed peripheral if it is either conjugate to the fundamental group of a totally geodesic boundary component or to the fundamental group of a cusp or $\partial$–cusp"
So this is the question I have: given a finite-volume hyperbolic $n$-manifold $M$ that is non-compact, or that has non empty totally geodesic boundary, is it true that the fundamental groups of the cusp, the $\partial$-cusp, and the boundary component inject into $\pi_1(M)$? If that is not the case, I cannot make much sense of the phrase above.

Yes, that is the case.

It is a nice exercise in working through definitions.
